# Ordering by two date fields, whichever one is more recent

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I want my objects ordered by latest date, either by updated date or created date, whichever one is more recent.  The problem with my code below is that objects that are not updated (which are null) appear at the bottom.

```
public IQueryable<MyObject> GetMyObjects()
{
    return from obj in _db.MyObjects
           orderby obj.UpdatedDate descending, obj.CreatedDate descending
           select obj;
}
```

Even if an object doesn't have an updated date, it should still appear before other objects that do have an updated date, if those objects' updated dates are less that this object's created date.  How can I achieve this? Basically, I want to order by latest date and use either the updated date or created date whichever one is later.

How should my linq code be changed to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: @Andrey: See my answer. The generated SQL looks correct.

Comment: Thanks guys...both the answers look like they will work for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if I have well understood what you're asking but here is my solution:

```
return from myclass in classes
       let updated = myclass.Updated ?? myclass.Created
       orderby updated descending
       select myclass;
```

Tested with a class named `MyClass`:

```
class MyClass
{
    public DateTime? Updated { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
}
```

And with these values:

```
MyClass[] classes = 
{
    new MyClass() { Created = DateTime.Now.AddDays(12)},
    new MyClass() { Created = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5), Updated = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3)},
    new MyClass() { Created = DateTime.Now},
    new MyClass() { Created = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2), Updated = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10)},
    new MyClass() { Created = DateTime.Now},
    new MyClass() { Created = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), Updated = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)},
    new MyClass() { Created = DateTime.Now},
    new MyClass() { Created = DateTime.Now.AddDays(20), Updated = DateTime.Now.AddDays(4)}
};
```

The result is:

```
Updated = null - Created = 22/03/2011
Updated = 20/03/2011 - Created = 12/03/2011
Updated = 14/03/2011 - Created = 30/03/2011
Updated = 13/03/2011 - Created = 05/03/2011
Updated = 11/03/2011 - Created = 11/03/2011
Updated = null - Created = 10/03/2011
Updated = null - Created = 10/03/2011
Updated = null - Created = 10/03/2011
```

Comment: Note that this code presumes that `Updated` will always be later than `Created`, which sounds like it *should* be true, but....

Comment: Fair enough but logically you first create an object and then you update it. So I think my presumption is acceptable :)

Answer (score 4):

I tried this query in LINQPad with the Northwind DB, and it worked fine:

```
from o in Orders
orderby o.RequiredDate > o.ShippedDate ? o.RequiredDate : o.ShippedDate
select new
{
    o.RequiredDate,
    o.ShippedDate
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I ended up using AS-CII's answer for now, but I have no doubt this would have worked too.